# Scilab how to replace a comma with a dot in an matrix

Tags: csv, matrix, replace, scilab

May I ask for some advice, please?
I have for homework process data from file which has this structure:

"Time;Track;Force
s;mm;N
0,020;0,253;0,060
0,040;0,320;0,030
0,060;0,387;0,060
0,080;0,453;0,060
0,100;0,520;-0,000
0,120;0,587;0,030
0,140;0,654;0,030
0,160;0,721;-0,000
0,180;0,787;0,030
0,200;0,854;0,030
0,220;0,921;0,030
0,240;0,988;-0,000"

To load the data to matrix I use this command:
csvRead("Pene_1.txt",[';'],[],"string")
However my issue with this, is that the dates I would need in double because I will need to do some calculate with them, but in Europe a decimal point is used as the data separator instead of a decimal point. **I would need to replace all of these decimal commas with decimal dots throughout the matrix**. Please does anyone how to do it? Thanks you very much :)
by the way there I put whole file :)
http://leteckaposta.cz/859703762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `csvRead("Pene_1.txt",';',',',"string")` the third parameter `','` defines the decimal separator.